# Beamer: Create two tables, one above the other

Tags: tables, beamer

I am using Beamer presentation, is it possible to create these two tables (I have create two tables that are equal) one above the other, considering the line-style that I have implemented?

[image]
[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {


\usetheme{Madrid}

}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\usepackage{caption, tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}



\title[Title]{Title}

\author{Name} 
\date{\today} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title} 
\tableofcontents 
\end{frame}


\section{Section}
\begin{frame}{Table}
   \begin{table}[h]
\caption{xxx}
\centering
    % \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth,center}
    \begin{adjustbox}{center}
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            % \centering
            \toprule
            \multirow{}{}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Model1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Model2}\\
            \midrule
            \multirow{}{}{Var1}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{...} 
                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{...} \\
            \multirow{}{}{Var2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{...} 
                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{...} \\
            \multirow{}{}{Var3}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{...} 
                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{...} \\
          \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
    % \vspace{ - 05 mm}
    \label{tab:xxx}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I have tried in this way, but I am not able to do more..

Comment: Please add a compilable code to the question. From `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: @SimonDispa You are right, I have edited the question!

Comment: The table is missing! It takes time to guess your style.

Comment: Do You want to make less space between tables? or no?

Comment: @SimonDispa I do not know how to create the table reported in the picture.. I just need something similar, if is it possible..

Comment: @WinnieNotThePooh Yes less space will be perfect!

Comment: @John_maddon just use \vspace{-1cm} between tables

Comment: Your example is not working. Remove the `\multirow` where it is not needed.

Comment: There is only one table in your example. Shell both tables have a caption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, that you looking for something like this:

[image]

MWE (Minimal Working Example), which s focused only tables, is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table}
   \begin{table}
   \footnotesize
\caption{xxx}
\label{tab:xxx}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{c cc cc}
    \toprule
\multirow{2.4}{*}{X}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{First} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Second}\\
    \cmidrule(r){2-3}  \cmidrule(l){4-5}
                    & Model 1 &  Model 2 & Model 1 &  Model 2    \\ 
    \midrule
Var1    & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
Var2    & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
Var3    & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\medskip
\caption{yyyy}
\begin{tabular}{c cc cc}
    \toprule
\multirow{2.4}{*}{X}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{First} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Second}\\
    \cmidrule(r){2-3}  \cmidrule(l){4-5}
                    & Model 1 &  Model 2 & Model 1 &  Model 2    \\
    \midrule
Var1    & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
Var2    & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
Var3    & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: that's perfect, thanks!